# SizedOverflowBox's size is not working as expected

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: SizedOverflowBox(
      size: Size(100, 100),
      child: Container(color: Colors.blue),
    ),
  );
}
```

[image]

I'm providing a `width` and `height` of `100` but it paints a rectangular `Container` with some arbitrary dimension. So, what `size` does in `SizedOverflowBox`?

Comment: Hi @iDecode, I want to address that the size of the SizedOverflowBox isn't the size of the widget. for example `size(x,y)` x and y control the horizontal and vertical alignment. you can try it on dartpad.dev to get better understanding, play with x, y and alignment then shrink and expand the code space or the widget space to see how the overflow works with the new values.

Answer (score 3):

As per described from official documentation:

"A widget that is a specific size but passes its original constraints through to its child, which may then overflow."

```
child: Container(
    color: Colors.orangeAccent,
    child: SizedOverflowBox(
      size: const Size(
        80.0,
        100.0,
      ),
      alignment: AlignmentDirectional.bottomStart,
      child: Container(
        height: 50.0,
        width: 150.0,
        color: Colors.blue,
      ),
    ),
  ),
```

This would produce this:
[image]

Reference for my description:
https://flutteragency.com/sizedoverflowbox-widget/

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, but my question wasn't asking for an example of how it can work. I already did this kind of thing. The question is what `size` is doing in my code, and why that arbitrary dimension?

Comment: The size you set is the constraint for your box. The container gets its "arbitrary" size from the parent of the box.

Comment: For your first sentence, the size I'm providing isn't providing any constraint at all. This isn't a `ConstrainedBox` but a `SizedOverflowBox`. For your second statement, can you tell me who is the parent of the box, and what size it constraints on its child?

Comment: @iDecode the problem is that you dont see your `SizedOverflowBox` since it has no visual representation - to make it more clear use `debugPaintSizeEnabled = true;` or just press `p` key if you run your app from the command line via `flutter run` command

Comment: @pskink Sir, I know the `size` is there, but I'm not understanding where those arbitrary dimensions are coming from.

Comment: It is constraints for the box itself, not its child. I know it isn't a ConstrainedBox, that is putting additional constraints for its child. As both I and pskink has pointed out, the child of SizedOverflowBox get its constraints from the parent of SizedOverflowBox. More info on constraints: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/layout/constraints

Comment: or rather wished size for the box itself , rather than constraints. Sorry for being unclear.

Comment: @pskink The parent of `SizedOverflowBox` is `Scaffold`, isn't it?

Comment: @pskink So, is `Scaffold` giving that arbitarary dimensions to `SizedOverflowBox`?

Comment: @pskink Sir, I read that post but couldn't find anything relevant to my question, I updated the question with a screenshot, can you see the size of the container being drawn, it is actually 0.5x width and height of the screen. Which of the parent constraints pass that from the `Scaffold`?

Answer (score 3):

So, here is how `SizedOverflowBox` works

these are the widget that `SizedOverflowBox` effects

1. parent
2. SizedOverflowBox
3. child

let parent widget has `x` width and `y` height.
`SizedOverflowBox` has `ox` width and `oy` height in its size parameter.
then the child widget will be given following constraints.

`maxWidth = ox + ((x - ox)/2)`
`maxHeight = oy + ((y - oy/2)/2)`

then child can't be greater than maxWidth and maxHeight even if we try provide greater hight and width values explicitly. But it can be smaller than maxWidth and maxHeight.

And the parent will have the following constraints

`minWidth = SizedOverflowBox.width`
`minHeight = SizedOverflowBox.height`
`maxWidth = parent.width`
`maxHeight = parent.height`

And, parent will think its child tree has maximum size of `ox`, `oy`. As these are the dimensions of `SizedOverflowBox` provided in its size parameter.

There is more to it.

If parent has size smaller than the size of child of SizedOverflowBox then the child of SizedOverflowBox won't be able to overflow. And if parent has `size < SizedOverflowBox.size` then `SizedOverflowBox` will use `parent.size` as its own `size` and pass the same constraints to the child as

`maxwidth = parent.size`
`maxHeight = parent.size`

Comment: Where did you get this formula `maxWidth = ox + ((x - ox)/2) maxHeight = oy + ((y - oy/2)/2)` from?

Comment: I deduced it from the implementation of SizedOverflowBlox. Although documentation says it passes the original constraints. But It does not work that way, it overflow its child by half of the parent available space.

Comment: If you can raise an issue on Github and once one of the members confirms your formula is correct, I'll happily accept it as answer. Thank you

Comment: I'm afraid I'll have to downvote your answer because you're not providing any source for your formula. Your answer will turn out to be "misleading" in such case.

Comment: I can't provide the source, as I already told you I figured it out, by implementing it in various scenarios

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because the default alignment of SizedOverflowBox is `Alignment.center`, **according to the Size(100,100) area**.

```
const SizedOverflowBox({
  Key? key,
  required this.size,
  this.alignment = Alignment.center,
  Widget? child,
}) : assert(size != null),
   assert(alignment != null),
   super(key: key, child: child);
```

The **Size** of the blue area is unlimited so it show as large as the parent widget `Scaffold`

So, it draw a blue rectangle as large as `Scaffold` and place in the center of `Size(100, 100)` area. (you can try to set alignment to **Alignment.topLeft** and see the whole rectangle
maybe you want)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The SizedOverFlow box has a specific size but it does not override the size of the parent, rather it sizes its parent widget and lets its child widget overflow the constraints.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: SizedOverflowBox(
      size: Size(100, 100),
      child: Container(color: Colors.blue),
    ),
  );
}
```

Size(100, 100), get assigned to the parent widget. So I wrap the SizedOverflowBox widget with a Container widget.

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.green,
          child: SizedOverflowBox(
            size: Size(100, 100),
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.blue,
              height: 50,
              width: 300,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

[image]

Comment: You said, `it does not override the size of the parent, rather it sizes its parent widget`, are you sure about it?

Comment: SizedOverFlow Box  sizes its parent widget and lets its child widget overflow the constraints